# Resolution Principle in First Order Logic

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

Suppose that we are in First Order Logic and we have a set of clauses.

I want to prove that a certain clause is a logical consequence of this set of clauses.

Is it correct to use the Resolution Principle in this case (negating the goal clause and deducing the empty clause)?

Comment: What do you mean by 'negating the goal clause'? Say the goal clause is $\{ A, B \}$ ... what would be the negated version of that clause?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Careful... What do you mean by 'negating the goal clause'? Say the goal clause is $\{ A, B \}$, what would be the negated version of that clause? You can't say it's $\neg \{ A, B \}$, that's nonsense... that's not even a clause.

And you don't want $\{ \neg A, \neg B \}$ either, since $\{ A, B \}$ corresponds to $A \lor B$, and so what you really want is $\neg A \land \neg B$, which corresponds to *two* clauses $\{ \neg A \}$ and $\{ \neg B \}$.

OK, but that is propositional logic. With FOL, things get a lot more hairy. For example, if the conclusion is $\forall x \ P(x)$, then putting that into a clause gives you $\{ P(x) \}$. But when you negate that, you should not get $\{ \neg P(x) \}$, for that would correspond to $\forall x \ \neg P(x)$, and what you want is of course the clause you would get for $\neg \forall x \ P(x)$, which is the clause for $\exists x \ \neg P(x)$, which is $\{ \neg P(c_0) \}$ with $c_0$ being a Skolem constant. And with multiple quantifiers, things get even more hairy, for now you may need function symbols for the Skolemization process.

So, my advice is to translate the 'goal clause' into a FOL statement, negate it, and work out the result so it can be put back into clauses. In fact, if you start with a set of FOL statements (which is what typically happens), I would definitely not take the goal statement, put into goal clause(s), and then try to negate that/those clause(s), but rather immediately negate the statement, and put that into clauses.

But yes, all these precautions set aside, you're right: If the negation of some clause $C$, when correctly put into (possibly multiple) clauses, when added to the original clause set, allows you to infer the empty clause, then that shows indeed that that clause $C$ logically follows forom the original clause set.

Comment: Wait , a clause $\{A,B\}$ means $A \land B$, doesn't it?

Comment: @Sudix No. In resolution we resolve $\{ A , B \}$ and $\{ \neg A, C \}$ to $\{ B, C \}$. This makes sense if $\{ A, B \}$ means $A \lor B$, but not if $\{ A, B \}$ means $A \land B$. Remember for resulotion we put statements into CNF, and then take each term of that CNF (which is a *disjunction*) and make that into a clause.

Comment: Ah, thank you. Why is $\exists x: \lnot P(x) \equiv \{P(c_0)\}$ and not $\{\lnot P(c_0)\}$?

Comment: @Sudix Ah, thank you! :) yes, that was a typo, thanks!

Comment: Suppose i put the statement i want to prove the logical consequence, into CNF. And i get $A\wedge B$. Is it correct to negate it, obtaining $notA \vee notB$ and now use the Resolution Principle ?

Comment: Ps : my initial doubt remains : If i want to prove that F is a logical consequences of a set of clauses, and i prove that notF gives an empty clause (with the Resolution Principle), then did i prove that F is a logical consequence of the set of clauses ?

Comment: @Qwerto Yes, I did confirm that at the end of my post. I just would like to advise against first putting the conclusion into clauses before negating it: much safer to first negate it and then putting it into clausal form.

Comment: Thanks so much, i tried to use your suggestions and it seems work. Can you check here ? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2814704/exercise-about-logical-consequences-in-first-order-logic

Comment: Anyway, the negated version of $\left \{ A,B \right \}$ is $notA\wedge notB $, that corresponds to the 2 separate clauses notA. and notB. . Isnt it ? In your answer, you wrote that  $notA\wedge notB $ corresponds to the 2 separate clauses notA. and B.