# Exercise about Logical Consequences in First Order Logic

Tags: first-order-logic

I have a set of clauses in CNF. I have to prove that $not[notR,notP,notQ]$ is **NOT** a logical consequence of this set of clauses.

What i did is :

1)The goal clause becomes : $R\wedge P\wedge Q$.I dont need to negate that the goal clause since i want to prove that it is NOT a logical consequence. I can rewrite the goal clause as :

R.

P.

Q.

2) Now, i have to use the resolution principle to obtain an empty clause. If i get it, then $not[notR,notP,notQ]$ is **NOT** a logical consequence of the set of clauses.

Is it correct ?

Comment: See your previous post : [resolution-principle-in-first-order-logic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2812652/resolution-principle-in-first-order-logic) and see [Resolution proof procedure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resolution_(logic)#A_resolution_technique).

Comment: Sorry, i edited my message. Is it correct now ?

Comment: See e.g. Mordechai Ben-Ari, [Mathematical Logic for Computer Science](https://books.google.it/books?id=TQ1n03kEBOkC&pg=PA77), Springer (3rd ed 2012), **Ch.4 Propositional Logic: Resolution** for review of definitions and basic symbolism : "The clausal form of formula is a notational variant of CNF. Recall that a literal is an atom or the negation of an atom. A clause is a set of literals. A clause is considered to be an implicit disjunction of its literals." 1/2

Comment: "The CNF formula: $(p ∨ r) ∧ (¬q ∨¬p ∨ q)$ is logically equivalent to its clausal form: $\{ \{ p, r \}, \{ ¬ q,¬p, q \} \}$. 2/2

Comment: Isnt possible to have three literals with AND beetween them as goal ? In Prolog it's possible.

Comment: What is $not[notR,notP,notQ]$ ? That's not your typical logic statement ... is that suposed to be a negation of a clause? There really isn't such a thing as a negation of a clause though ...

Comment: I found in a exercise given by my prof. I think is the equivalent of $not(notR\vee notP\vee notQ)$

Comment: I have applied DeMorgan and i rewrited it as 3 clauses

Comment: It seems correct to me . What do you think ?

Comment: @Qwerto No; not for demonstrating *non*-consequence .. see my Answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so suppose you add the clauses $\{ A \}$, $\{ B \}$, and $\{ C \}$, to your clause set, and you are able to derive an empty clause. Well, that means that your original clause set $\Gamma$, together with these three clauses leads to a contradiction. Well, that means that the original clause set $\Gamma$ logically implies the negation of $A \land B \land C$, i.e the original clause set implies $\neg A \lor \neg B \lor \neg C$.

OK, but that does *not* mean that its negation is *not* a logical consequence of that clause set. For example, if the original clause set contains a contradiction, then it will logically imply both  $\neg A \lor \neg B \lor \neg C$ as well as $\neg (\neg A \lor \neg B \lor \neg C)$

So, what you need to do instead is to find an assignment that sets all of the clauses in $\Gamma$ to true, but that sets $\neg (\neg A \lor \neg B \lor \neg C)$ to false, i.e. $\neg A \lor \neg B \lor \neg C$ to true. Or, in other words, you need to show that the set of statements $\Gamma \cup \neg A \lor \neg B \lor \neg C$ is consistent.

Now, I am not sure resolution is the best method for this, since resolution is really a method to show inconsistency, rather than consistency. The only way to use resolution to show consistency of $\Gamma \cup \neg A \lor \neg B \lor \neg C$, is to start with $\Gamma \cup \neg A \lor \neg B \lor \neg C$ as your clauses, and to then demonstrate (in a meta-sort-of-way) that at some point it is impossible to generate any new clauses, while *not* having derived a contradiction.  But, my advise is to use a different method. Do you have few enough variables to just do a simple truth-table?

Comment: Yes, ill do a truth table. Anyway i still not understand one thing. If i apply the Resolution Principle with $not(notA \vee  notB)$ (without negating it further) and i get an empty clause , it simply means that "is impossible that $(notA \vee  notB)$ is false ,than $(notA \vee  notB)$ must be a logical consequence. Isn't this the main idea of the Resolution Principle ?
Or i'm wrong and in reality the Resolution Principle indicates only some cases when $(notA \vee  notB)$ is true, and not the fact the is a logical consequence. Is this the case ?

Comment: @Qwerto The first one: If you add $\neg (\neg A \lor \neg B)$ and you get an empty clause, then that means that $\neg A \lor \neg B$ is a logical consequence of the other clauses. But agina, that does not mean that $\neg (\neg A \lor \neg B)$ is not a logical consequence; both a statement and its negation can be consequences ... if the original set of clauses contains a contradiction already.

Comment: Then, if i add (notA AND notB) and i get the empty clause, i've proved that not(notA AND notB) is a logical consequence of the set of clauses ?

Comment: @Qwerto Correct!   And please note that adding $\neg A \land \neg B$ means adding *two* clauses $\neg A$ and $\neg B$